# DAO to .mdb, ADO to .mdf comparison

Tags: sql-server, ado, dao, jet, recordset

This code editing a recordset based on joined tables works in DAO/.mdb database

```
     RS.Edit 
            RS.fields("fieldA").value = 0  'in table A
            RS.fields("fieldB").value = 0  ' in table B                
     RS.Update
```

The code was converted to ado on a sql server database and it failed with an error message:

> Run-time error '-2147467259' (80004005)' :
>   Cannot insert or update columns from multiple tables.

However it appears to work if it is altered like so :

```
            RS.fields("fieldA").value = 0  'in table A
     RS.Update
            RS.fields("fieldB").value = 0  ' in table B                
     RS.Update
```

Is this a normal way to do things with sql server or is there a gotcha to it.
I ask because when trying to find a solution (before I put in the extra update statement) I changed the recordset type to batchoptimistic and I got no error messge but only one table's record was edited.

Comment: What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: @Heinzi, Sorry I should have done that, I have edited the question to put in the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the data source of your recordset is an SQL returning data from multiple tables. Yes, it's normal that you can only update one table at a time. If you want to update values from multiple tables in a single, atomic step (so that no other client use can read the "intermediate value", where one table is changed but the other is not), you need to [use a transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905921.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, yes transactions now look more necessary
since it is now not just 1 update as it was in the DAO scenario.
But otherwise I am glad to know that it is an OK way to do it